# Azure Table Storage data modeling considerations

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I have a list of users. A user can either login either using username or e-mail address.

As a beginner in azure table storage, this is what I do for the data model for fast index scan.

```
PartitionKey    RowKey                        Property
users:email     jacky@email.com               nickname:jack123
users:username  jack123                       email:jacky@email.com
```

So when a user logs in via email, I would supply `PartitionKey eq users:email` in the azure table query. If it is `username`, `Partition eq users:username`.

Since it doesn't seem possible to simulate `contains` or `like` in azure table query, I'm wondering if this is a normal practice to store multiple row of data for 1 user ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since it doesn't seem possible to simulate contains or like in azure
>   table query, I'm wondering if this is a normal practice to store
>   multiple row of data for 1 user ?Since it doesn't seem possible to
>   simulate contains or like in azure table query, I'm wondering if this
>   is a normal practice to store multiple row of data for 1 user ?

This is a perfectly valid practice and in fact is a recommended practice. Essentially you will have to identify the attributes on which you could potentially query your table storage and somehow use them as a combination of `PartitionKey` and `RowKey`.

Please see [`Guidelines for table design`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-design-guidelines) for more information. From this link:

> ***Consider storing duplicate copies of entities***. Table storage is cheap so consider storing the same entity multiple times (with
>   different keys) to enable more efficient queries.